# based on custom request header value can we set spring-cloud-gateway path,please advise if any sample examples

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to do small proof of concept using spring cloud gateway.
i have 5 microservices to call.from frontend ui i am trying to call spring-cloud-gateway service which i have configured using java config .
its all working with simple case however i am planning to set path dynamically based on custom header fields:
example:if journey-type=train then predicate.path need to set train-service and
if journey-type=car then predicate.path need to set car-service . is it possible to set dynamically.

What are the patterns we can implement here ,is it Global Filter better or Gateway filter.
 `@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {`

```
 @Bean
    public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(r -> r
                        .path("/abc/v1.0/train/**")
                        .filters(f->f.filter(new TrainFilter()))
                        .uri("http://localhost:8082/")
                        .id("addressModule"))

                .route(r -> r.path("/abc/v1.0/car/**")
                        .uri("http://localhost:8083/")
                        .id("consumerModule"))
                .build();
    }
```

}
Filter code
@Slf4j
public class TrainFilter implements GatewayFilter {

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    log.info("BEFORE in SimpleFilter.....called");
     HttpHeaders headers = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders();
     List<String>  journeyKey = headers.get("JOURNEY-TYPE"); 
     System.out.println(journeyKey);
     if(!journeyKey.isEmpty() && journeyKey.get(0).equals("CAR")) {
         System.out.println("its train..journey type ");
                return chain.filter(exchange);
        }
     
     else {
    
         org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse =exchange.getResponse();
        serverHttpResponse.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
        byte[] response = "{\"status\":error\",\"message\":\"error occured\"}".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer buffer = exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(response);
        return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Flux.just(buffer));
        
    }
    

}
```

not sure..what is the best way ,please advise..based on header field value can we set the path dynamically?like Abstract level,thanks in Advance for looking into this